# Script execution is suspended or getting aborted when running in parallel with thread count 5

Tags: karate

Details: I'm trying to run my test scripts through TestRunner class. When using. parallel() method with thread count 5 or more, the script execution is getting suspended or getting aborted in the middle. I'm using karate-core version 1.2.0 currently and I'm facing this issue. When running with. parallel(1) no issues are encountered.

Below code executing properly

```
@Test

public void testParallel() {

        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:feature").tags().outputCucumberJson(true).outputJunitXml(true).parallel(1);
        }
```

Below code with thread count 5 is getting suspended or getting aborted in the middle.

```
@Test
 
public void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:feature").tags().outputCucumberJson(true).outputJunitXml(true).parallel(5);
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: first - we don't support old versions, so upgrade. second, no one has reported this so unless you can follow this process - it is unlikely that anyone else can help you with this. it may be an issue with the way your tests are written: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue